# Unfortunately, FTest has stopped

Tags: android

```
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eeee.ftest/com.eeee.ftest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at com.eeee.ftest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
06-25 18:30:30.885: E/AndroidRuntime(26556):    ... 11 more


public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab Frag1 = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment 1");
        ActionBar.Tab Frag2 = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment 2");
        ActionBar.Tab Frag3 = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment 3");

        Fragment Fragment1 = new Fragment_1();
        Fragment Fragment2 = new Fragment_2();
        Fragment Fragment3 = new Fragment_3();

        Frag1.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment1));
        Frag2.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment2));
        Frag3.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(Fragment3));

        actionbar.addTab(Frag1);
        actionbar.addTab(Frag2);
        actionbar.addTab(Frag3);


    }

    class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener{

        public Fragment fragment;

        public MyTabsListener(Fragment fragment){
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Another Android NPE? People go learn what an NPE is already... or better, go learn Java.

Answer (score 0):

When using ActionBarSherlock hiding the TitleBar will also mean hiding the ActionBar.

So remove requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);